# Script to log on to website, check for changes and email if changed

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I'm hoping to write a simple script that will log on to a specific website (email as username, no pw required) and check for changes.  If there are any changes I'd like to receive an email notification simply stating that there has been an update.  Ideally this script would run fairly often, maybe every 10 minutes.

Since I don't want to have to have my laptop open for this to occur I was thinking that my Rasberry Pi (always on and currently used for xbmc) should be running the script in the background.

I've seen lots of scripts to check websites for changes but none of them fit the senario of needing to log in but without a password.  Furthermore, after establishing that there has been a change I'm not sure how the sending an email part would work, would I have to install an email program on the Raspi?  Basically all I do/kind of know is Linux basics and how to schedule this script using cron.

So, is there a simple-ish script that could do this?  Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The relevant part of the login page is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/booking/nanny_view/show" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="zH92kuR1rZAHqpfRUnrsB6Y9qRWJOZ46jnAao3xZOvA=" />
  </div>
  <p>
    Email Address: 
    <input id="search_email" name="search[email]" size="30" type="text" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: What sort of login are you talking about? Form/Cookie? HTTP built-in?

Comment: I'm not sure, the website is www.nanniesoncall.com/booking/nanny_view/show

Comment: I edited the login mechanism into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the script at fixed times can be done with `cron`.

Posting your mail address to the site should be possible with `wget`:

```
wget --post-data='search[email]=me@foo.com' www.nanniesoncall.com/booking/nanny_view/show
```

(You might need to send the other fields, too. - Especially the "authenticity_token" might cause you trouble. )

For parsing the result page, maybe a simple `grep` is enough.

For a more sophisticated solution have a look at `mechanize`, a library for perl, python, and ruby, which makes sending data and parsing results very comfortable.

Comment: So, the script would go something like: wget, grep to parse and compare to previous results and then $ echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" someone@somewhere.com to mail the results?  What exactly do you mean by "send the other fields"?

Comment: Your question now shows the relevant part of the web page. It shows a form containing some elements. Each element has a name and a value. Those name-value pairs are send with a post request to the server. `wget` sends exactly this post request and returns the answer of the server. You need to test for yourself with valid data.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize is much easier than pure command line tools.
Here is a basic ruby script checking your page:

```
require 'mechanize'

page=Mechanize.new.get('http://www.nanniesoncall.com/booking/nanny_view/show')
form=page.forms.first
form["search[email]"]="me@foo.com"
result=form.submit

puts result.at("#main")
```

You probably have to adapt the last line to show you the information you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I'll have to figure out how to do the emailing and checking for changes part in python now.